# Можно ли переделать код?

Tags: c++, строки

Необходимо вывести строку, сформированную из исходной строки, в порядке увеличения количества символов в слове.

В качестве примера дан такой код:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const string str = "Eniki beniki eli vareniki";
    string result;
    istringstream ist(str);
    for (string word; ist >> word; result += word + " ")
        sort(word.begin(), word.end());
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Он выводит строку, в которой все буквы в словах расположены в алфавитном порядке.

Пример вывода:

```
Eiikn beiikn eil aeiiknrv
```

Помогите переделать текущий код или написать новый, чтобы решить задачу.

Comment: Из этого кода вы можете использовать выделение отдельных слов. Сложите их в вектор и отсортируйте, используя сравнение по длине